# OpenID Delegation

Tags: openid, delegation

I have tried all the possible options to use openID delegation on my site, but none of the methods are working for me.

1. I'm having the "link rel" tags in the head section of the HTML file.
2. I'm having the xrds location meta tags in the head section of the HTML file.
3. I'm setting HTTP Headers for X-XRDS-Location and X-YADIS-Location.
4. I've put redirection rules in the .htaccess file to send a XRDF file in case that type is requested using "Accept" header.

I'm not sure whats wrong, but none of the services can find the openID endpoint successfully. Verified [here](http://www.openidenabled.com/resources/openid-test/checkup/) and [here](http://www.clickpass.com/).

I'm trying to use http://vinuth.com/ as the openID URL and access to that page uses all the methods described above. I've verified the correctness of all the URLs used in those head tags. I've also tried permutations of using only one or two of these methods selectively.

tags I've put under head:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="https://pip.verisignlabs.com/server/" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://gubbi.pip.verisignlabs.com/" />
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/user/gubbi/yadis" />
<meta http-equiv="X-YADIS-Location" content="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/user/gubbi/yadis" />
```

Asking for help in a state of frustration overflow. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it should work ;)

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://gubbi.pip.verisignlabs.com" />
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server" />
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://gubbi.pip.verisignlabs.com" />
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/user/gubbi/yadisxrds" />
<meta http-equiv="X-YADIS-Location" content="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/user/gubbi/yadisxrds" />
```

no need to do anything fancy ;)

Comment: You need to remove the trailing slashes otherwise you will get endpoint mismatch errors. See: https://pip.verisignlabs.com/faq.do#faq17

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://pip.verisignlabs.com/faq.do#faq17):

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server/" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://gubbi.pip.verisignlabs.com/" />
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server/" />
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://gubbi.pip.verisignlabs.com/" />
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/user/gubbi/yadisxrds" />
<meta http-equiv="X-YADIS-Location" content="http://pip.verisignlabs.com/user/gubbi/yadisxrds" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the protocol on the openid.server to http instead of https and see if that works. Also, I think you'll want to set <link rel="openid2.provider" href="..." /> to the same value you are using for openid.server, to cover all the bases.

Comment: Yeah, tried both now. i.e., changing https to http and adding the openid2.provider rel links.. Neither works. 

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good test RP:

http://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx

After the failure, click "Recent Logs" to see what the verbose details are of what the RP was trying to do.  It might help you figure out what you're doing wrong.

I suggest you pull out all your YADIS and XRDS stuff and stick to the simple HTML LINK tags until you get it right.  It keeps the unknowns down.